# How to see my Out-Of-Office history in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I periodically set my Out-Of-Office in Outlook if I'm, well, out of the office or something.  I'd like to look back over when I set it.

Does Outlook keep a log of my Out-Of-Office history?

Comment: Unfortunately (to my knowledge) it's not possible.  This feature is stored in a set variable and is overwritten when a new out of office message is created.

You can only view the most recent message & settings by going into the out of office assistant (where it'll show until it's changed again).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm kind of surprised I can't find anyone else asking this question.  Any other suggestions? I'm technically inclined so I don't mind digging.

Comment: The only record I can think of is your Sent messages. Maybe filter by the out of office message however if you hadn't received an email on a specific day then it won't appear... Other downfall is how long your sent messages are kept for.

Comment: Yeah, it is funny: there are 3 big ridiculous buttons  `Translate to Chinese...`, but it is not possible to trace OoO mails...

Answer (score 1):

Joe S, Outlook doesn't appear to keep a copy of out of office messages in Sent Items, at least not when connected to an Exchange server. You can check the Exchange message tracking logs if you've got access to them, but they likely won't go back very far.

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Answer (score -2):

You can check the past OOO dates in your outlook calendar . Hope it helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1081989)

Comment: @zx485 It does attempt to answer the question. It might not be a good answer, but that's what downvotes are for, not deletion. See [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/4284627).

Comment: @DonaldDuck: I'll have a look at it. thx for the info.